# Is there a free private Bazaar online source host?

Tags: version-control, hosting, dvcs, bazaar

I am looking for a free private online Bazaar source host. Does anybody know of any? I had a quick look and it seems there are lots of Git, Mercurial, and SVN options, but no Bazaar?

Just to clarify, when I say "private" I mean in the sense that you get your own private repository where you can grant access to people you choose.

Comment: AFAIK Git (github) does not offer private hosting for free, only for small fee. Mercurial (bitbucket) does.

Comment: wow - it's been ages since I asked this question. If anyone is interested, although Launchpad was the best Bazaar online hosting solution, I ended up using Bitbucket, which is not Bazaar, but Mercurial. I found launchpad/Bazaar to be a little difficult to use, whereas I found bitbucket/Mercurial to be quite intuitive (for me). Bitbucket also supports private repos (you can determine who has access to view/check-in/etc). Anyway, hopefully that information helps someone out!

Comment: Not sure if it did at the time of your asking, but Bitbucket also supports Git.  I am still looking for a free private Bazaar host.

Comment: Yep, I asked this question before Bitbucket did Git. Now I use Git instead of Mercurial on Bitbucket! Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://launchpad.net - free bazaar hosting... but I don't know what do you mean by access - I think that is has same functionalisty as github (we are using it working with Moovida) but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Yes, we tried launchpad. Unfortunately, I do not believe they allow for making repositories private (as in you can restrict access to the repos)/

Comment: @Andrew: you can make private repositories on LP, but you have to pay for that.

Comment: Launchpad now offers private Launchpad hosting, including Bazaar repositories. It's on the order of US$250/year, and apparently they're fairly flexible since it's early days. 

http://blog.launchpad.net/general/new-privacy-features-for-commercial-subscribers

Answer (score 8):

Bazaar can host branches over FTP. So if you have free private FTP hosting you can use it for free private bzr repository.

Comment: except that bzr uses a dumb protocol over FTP which really hurts performances

Answer (score 6):

Two options for you :

**The really private, with team support :**

- Use a private SFTP or FTPS server. If you already have a web host you probably can use it for this. You can also serve a personal SFTP/FTPS server on your computer (for example you can use *OpenSSH* for SFTP or *Pure-FTP* or *VSFTPD* for FTPS, all of which are quick to setup on a Linux and Unix machines).

**The personal sandbox , without team :**

- At *Launchpad* ! You can freely use a personal "junk" repo at Launchpad, but without team support. Very useful if your are working on a starter project but do not want to publish it to early. You can also use it for home<->work exchanges.
  See https://help.launchpad.net/Code/PersonalBranches

Answer (score 2):

I just found out my current web hosting provider (http://www.webfaction.com) provides 1-command installation of bzr, plus easy instructions for installing loggerhead.  Possibly others do as well, but this is the first one I've heard of.

http://docs.webfaction.com/software/bazaar.html

Answer (score 0):

[Launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net)

Its the home of the ubuntu disto, but its open to host any project and they use bazaar as their primary VCS tool.

Comment: It isn't free for private projects.

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Hosting for a list of known hosting providers for Bazaar. There are no free hosters of private branches that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that [Codebase](http://www.codebasehq.com/) provides free plan with one project/repo: git, svn, mercurial or bazaar, at your choice.